# In my keyboard, keys G and H, stopped working but till past two days before it worked. Pls do help me out

Tags: keyboard

I tried cleaning the keyboard too...tried few sudo commands too
like :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all
```

which I saw it in one of the answers here on this website.

Pls help me out, as its annoying to copy paste,g and h again and again.
As I am a student and require my laptop for my assignments :(.

English is not my first language so pls pardon me for it.

Comment: Boot to BIOS / UEFI prompt and try there. If the problem still persists, it is a hardware problem.

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; so we can't provide specific help. I'd test with another keyboard, and contrast what you see with tools like `xev`